# A poker deck has $52$ cards, $13$ ranks ${A,2,...,10,J,Q,K}$ and $4$ suits {diamond, club, heart, spade}.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, poker

A poker deck has $52$ cards, $13$ ranks $\{A,2,...,10,J,Q,K\}$ and $4$ suits {diamond, club, heart, spade}. If $5$ cards are dealt, what is the probability that there is an ace of diamonds?

Here is my thinking: event over the sample space, which is event of getting
(ace of diamonds)/ $\begin{pmatrix} 52 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$.

then for the event: _ _ _ _ _. We got 5 chances which is $\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, then for the ace of diamonds $\begin{pmatrix} 52 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $since there is only one ace of a diamond from the $52$ cards. so $\frac{ \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 52 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}} {\begin{pmatrix} 52 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}}$? is this right?

What about if we just count of the p(ace) and P(a diamond)?   Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of looking at the problem, which might be even easier to digest, is that the probability that you *do* get an ace of diamonds is very simply $1$ minus the probability that you *don't* get the ace of diamonds.

The number of five card hands total is $\binom{52}{5}$, each of which are equally likely to have occurred (*which allows us to calculate probabilities by taking ratios*).  The number of five card hands which *don't* contain the ace of diamonds is $\binom{51}{5}$.

The probability is then:

$$1 - \dfrac{\binom{51}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

This generalizes easily to the other problems you seem interested in, the probability that within your five card hand you have at least one ace.  The probability that you get at least one ace is $1$ minus the probability you got no aces.  The number of hands with no aces would be $\binom{48}{5}$, so the probability of at least one ace is:

$$1 - \dfrac{\binom{48}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

Similarly, the probability of getting at least one diamond is $1 - \dfrac{\binom{39}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$

Answer (score 2):

An easier reasoning is: I am dealt $5$ cards out of $52$.

So possibilities I am satisfied are $5$ (cards I am dealt) out of $52$: $P=\frac{5}{52}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.
For the event, there's the ace of diamonds and some other $4$ cards from the remaining $51$, which can be chosen in $\binom{51}4$ ways. Hence, the answer is

$$\frac{\binom{51}4}{\binom{52}5}.$$

---

For just aces, the idea is similar, but a bit more complicated.
We must consider cases.
A hand of $5$ cards that contains an ace comes in four flavors:

- **It contains exactly one ace.** Then we must choose *one* of four aces in $\binom 41$ ways and the remaining four cards from among the $48$ non-ace cards in $\binom{48}4$ ways.
- **It contains exactly two aces.** Then we must choose *two* of four aces in $\binom 42$ ways and the remaining *three* cards from among the $48$ non-ace cards in $\binom{48}3$ ways.
- **It contains exactly three aces.** Then we must choose *three* of four aces in $\binom 42$ ways and the remaining *two* cards from among the $48$ non-ace cards in $\binom{48}2$ ways.
- **It contains exactly four aces.** Then we must choose *four* of four aces in $\binom 44$ ways and the remaining *one* card from among the $48$ non-ace cards in $\binom{48}1$ ways.

This gives us

$$\frac{\binom 41\binom{48}4 + \binom 42\binom{48}3 + \binom 43\binom{48}2 + \binom 44\binom{48}1}{\binom{52}5} = \frac1{\binom{52}5}\left(\sum_{k=1}^4\binom 4k \binom{48}{5-k}\right).$$

---

With this, do you think you can handle the case of just diamonds? It's similar.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit  why ${51 \choose 4 }$ again. but understand much with current statements. Can you also talk about P(ace ) and p(diamonds)? need an example to distinguish them .

Comment: ${51 \choose 4}$ seem like a complement, right? just like pretending the  ace of diamonds is chosen, then only left 51 card for the the 4 spaces left?

Comment: That's correct. The number of hands that contain an ace of diamonds is the number of ways to choose $4$ cards out of the the remaining $51$ (because the fifth card must be the ace of diamonds).

Comment: What about the P(ace) ? and P(diamond)?

Comment: What about it?  The probability that a specific card is the ace of diamonds is the same as the probability that it is an ace and is a diamond...  I don't understand what sort of difference you expect to see with one phrasing of an answer and a different phrasing of an answer.

Comment: I have edited the answer wiht P(ace). The idea is similar but benefits from considering cases. I have left the case of P(diamond) for you to try.

Comment: I also encourage you to look at JMoravitz's answer. Complimentary probability (calculating the problem of what you *don't* want to occur) can often lead to solutions with less work. It's a good tool to have in your arsenal!